# How "euch" makes a difference?

Tags: pronoun, reflexive

What is the difference between the sentences below? How does *euch* modify the meaning?

> Seht euch mal eure Liste an!
>   Seht mal eure Liste an!

Answer (score 0):

> Seht euch mal eure Liste an.

I try to translate with comments:

> You<sub>*plural*</sub> have a look at your list.

Normally in English you don't use the leading »You«, so the standard-translation would be:

> Have a look at your list.

Now let's look in the 2<sup>nd</sup> sentence:

> Seht mal eure Liste an.

This simply is:

> Have a look at your list.

So, if you translate both sentences into English, you end up with the same translation.

In German there is a marginal difference in the meaning of:

> 1. Sich etwas ansehen.
> 2. Etwas ansehen.

2 just means: *to watch something*, *to look at something*. But in 1 you pay more attention on what you are looking at. It's just the grade of attention that makes the difference.